# When are levy flights superdiffusive and why?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, random-walk, levy-processes

A [stable distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_distribution) that is centered and symmetrical has a value $\alpha \leq 1$ the expected value of the distribution is undefined.

I have also been told that if a [Levy Flight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy_flight) has it's step lengths drawn from the absolute of the stable distribution it will become [superdiffusive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anomalous_diffusion) when $\alpha = 1$ but not when $2 \geq \alpha > 1$.

Is it true that levy flights would only be superdiffusive when $\alpha \leq 1$ and why is that?

Comment: I might have a better chance of getting an answer on Physics but I read that the rules forbid cross posting. Could I post this as is on physics and delete it here or is this a better fit on math stack exchange?